# Other reasons for sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.4

I'm checking whether a given transactionid exists in my sqlite database with this code.

```
print((transaction.transactionid,))
print(type(transaction.transactionid))
c.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT transactionid FROM Transactions WHERE transactionid=?);", 
          (transaction.transactionid,))
self.dbconn.commit()
transaction_exists, = c.fetchone()
print(transaction_exists)
```

It always fails with this error on the second iteration:

> File "RtMetaMaster.py", line 182, in sync_ticket_to_db
>       (transaction.transactionid,)) sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Output of the print statements:

```
('626007',)
<class 'str'>
0    
('625952',)
<class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [..]
  File "RtMetaMaster.py", line 182, in sync_ticket_to_db
    (transaction.transactionid,))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Both times the transactionid is of type class 'str' but it somehow fails the second time. What other mistakes could lead to "Error binding parameter"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a self.dbconn.commit() after every c.execute call. There's probably a better solution for this.