# sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type only on some systems

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have a SQLite table in Python:

`conn.execute('create table if not exists users (id integer primary key, username text, fullname text, points integer)')`

Then I'm querying this table:

```
pk = int(like['pk']) #just some integer
users = conn.execute('select * from users where id = ?', (pk,))
```

I'm getting the following error:

`sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.`

Here's the catch: this code works perfectly on my Mac without errors, but it fails on my Raspberry Pi, C.H.I.P. (with Debian installed), and my friend's Mac.

I've seen [Other reasons for sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498628/other-reasons-for-sqlite3-interfaceerror-error-binding-parameter-0-probably-u) though it didn't work.

I've also seen [Error binding parameter 0: probably unsupported type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981709/error-binding-parameter-0-probably-unsupported-type?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) too but whatever I change my `(pk,)` too, no avail.

Why would this happen on some systems and not on some systems, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post a MCVE that we can test against? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve